How to Rename a Python Package and Update All Imports Automatically?
I downloaded a Python package from the pure_python branch of the mistree repository using:
pip install git+https://github.com/knaidoo29/mistree.git@pure_python

The package is installed with a different name (mistree_pp), but I want to rename it to mistree across the entire project. This includes renaming the directory and updating all the import statements that currently use mistree_pp to mistree.
How can I achieve this easily, without manually changing all the names and paths in the codebase?
I'm using Windows 11, but cross-platform solutions are welcome.

Across what project? The project using that module?

For the heck of it, I made a branch that renames mistree_pp back to mistree (and modernizes packaging etc. a bit): git+https://github.com/akx/mistree.git@pure-python-rename-back

@AKX Yeah across the project using the module 'mistree'! Thank you! Just out of curiosity, did you change module name across the entire repo manually or is there any command which simplifies the process?

The project itself didn't refer to its imports with mistree_pp, it used relative imports, so there wasn't anything to change there. The packaging and other stuff did though.

@INNA grep -Flrw --include=\*.py mistree_pp . | xargs sed -i 's/\bmistree_pp\b/mistree/g'

To answer the question on how to do it automatically, there are a bunch of tools who are specialized in doing this. "Refactoring" is typically the keyword you are looking for. A bunch of modern IDEs can do that out of the box, I guess most of the tools that work with an LSP (language server protocol) can do refactoring as well. It's a very common task, there is no mystery. -- And as other have said, it is not that hard to do it by hand either, it should be very straightforward.
